# Connect PHP Laravel app to local Firebase emulator

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I am using https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php to setup my Laravel app for Firebase connectivity. Now, I also have Firebase emulator running on http://localhost:5000/firebase but I am stuck with how am I able to connect my Laravel app to the local emulator instead of initiating it with the Google Service Account JSON file.

```
$factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/FirebaseKey.json');
```

I have tried the below for initiating the factory

```
$factory->withDatabaseUri('http://localhost:4000/firestore');
```

and I get the below error message when I run

```
Kreait\Firebase\Exception\RuntimeException
Unable to create a FirestoreClient: Error rendering 'projects/{project=*}/databases/{database=*}': expected binding 'project' to match segment '{project=*}', instead got null Provided bindings: Array ( [project] => [database] => (default) )
http://localhost:8000/firebase
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using the Firebase Emulator is not possible with current versions (<= 5.x) of the Firebase Admin SDK for PHP.

Comment: Does it work with the first line of code shared?

Comment: @jeromegamez, so it means that for PHP, we have to do the development using the cloud only? This seems to be expensive for the in-development mode. Also, with nodeJS is it possible to connect to local firebase emulator suite? If yes, can you share some information on this as well, please.

Comment: @ralemos, it does connect with the cloud and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. It's an unofficial SDK and I can only work on it in my unfunded spare time (of which I haven't much at the moment). It works with NodeJS and other official SDKs because Google has a larger, dedicated team working on it. Please also note that the Firebase Emulator is a fairly new component - this unofficial SDK will always lag behind feature-wise, but I like to think that it's still better than having no SDK for PHP at all 

Comment: @jeromegamez firstly thank you very much for the clarifications & definitely thankyou providing the PHP SDK and definitely it's worth much more than not having one. Your efforts are much appreciated by the community. I will work on the cloud version for the development as its still worth the effort when I tried with the official SDK.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words! Also, please don't think that I don't *want* to provide this functionality, I really much think it's useful, and it's definitely on the roadmap - I added it a couple of weeks ago with https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/issues/456 - if you'd like, you can subscribe to the ticket to keep track of its progress (but as always I can't give an ETA )

Comment: We work around this by calling cloud functions in firebase from PHP via http requests which will work with the emulators as well